# PDF417 decoder for python

Tags: python, decode, pdf417

I've looked everywhere and I've only found information related to generating PDF417 codes, but nothing regarding how to decode them. Is there a library to decode them in python? I'm already detecting the code in an image and croping it, but now I need a decoder.

Comment: I don't think there is anything decent in python / yet but https://www.silverbaytech.com/files/pdf417/pdf_api.pdf is a good starting point and the GPL2 C code at https://github.com/estebandelaf/pdf417decode looks promising

Comment: The easiest option to use is probably just `pdf417decoder`, as long as your barcodes are scan-quality. https://github.com/sparkfish/pdf417decoder If you need something "heavier" you can try looking at `pyzbar` https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/v2e4lisp/pdf417-text-mode-decoder) little piece of code, which does just what I want. It decodes PDF417 barcodes. Doesn't seem to be that robust though, so I'll guess I'll have to give the images some strong processing to extract only the barcode.

Answer (score 3):

There are two libraries that I know of for decoding PDF417 barcodes.

You can checkout [python-zxing](https://github.com/dlenski/python-zxing) which is a python wrapper for the ZXing decoder or you can use [pdf417decoder](https://github.com/sparkfish/pdf417decoder) which is a native Python port of a [C# PDF417 decoder library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4042463/PDF417-Barcode-Decoder-NET-Class-Library-and-Two-D).

ZXing requires files to be saved to the disk first while pdf417decoder can take a PIL Image object directly.